# display single array json data in android?

Tags: android, json

i am trying to display json data in an android application but i have having difficulty i think is may have to do with the way the json file was formated .i want to get the value of name and code in the headers array. and it is not working

this is the json file

```
 {
"status": "SUCCESS",
"headers": 
{
"id": "4",
"name": "GLO",
"code": "GLO",
"background_color_code": "15B709",
"text_color_code": "ffffff",
"statusMessage": "Hi +234805, an ACCESS FEE of N20.00 will be charged in order to access this Platform"
},
"statusMessage": "Movies Loaded successfully",
"caption": "Discover"
}
```

this is the java code

```
 protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> categoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            jParser = new JSONParser();

            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL_CATEGORY);

            try {
                  JSONObject categories =json.getJSONObject("headers");

                   String state = categories.getString("name");
                    String status = categories.getString("code");

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_PIC, state);
                    map.put(TAG_NOTE, status);
                    categoryList.add(map);


            }catch (Throwable e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return categoryList;
        }
```

this is the error

```
07-25 11:05:50.766  15683-15697/com.example.cann I/System.out﹕ close [socket][/10.187.206.124:36118]
07-25 11:05:50.781  15683-15702/com.example.cann W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value  at headers of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-25 11:05:50.782  15683-15702/com.example.cann W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
07-25 11:05:50.782  15683-15702/com.example.cann W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:613)
07-25 11:05:50.782  15683-15702/com.example.cann W/System.err﹕ at com.example.cann.CategoryActivity$LoadComments.doInBackground(CategoryActivity.java:81)
07-25 11:05:50.782  15683-15702/com.example.cann W/System.err﹕ at com.example.cann.CategoryActivity$LoadComments.doInBackground(CategoryActivity.java:60)
```

Comment: are you able to get data in getJSONFromUrl method ? try to print response and put it here

Comment: What do you get here `JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL_CATEGORY);`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
try {
    JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(Your_URL);
    JSONArray jsonArray = reader.getJSONArray("headers");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject e = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String name= e.getString("name");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 try {
        JSONObject rootJsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        if (rootJsonObject.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS")) {
            JSONObject headerJsonObject = new JSONObject(rootJsonObject.getString("headers"));
            String name = headerJsonObject.getString("name");
            String code = headerJsonObject.getString("code");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: where does the response varable come from

Comment: that is the server response in string

Comment: this is what i am getting   07-25 12:10:49.206  28912-28926/? W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
07-25 12:10:49.208  28912-28926/? W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)

Comment: JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL_CATEGORY);String response = json.toString();

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson ([Complete Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html/)) or Jackson ([Complete Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/))

Answer (score 0):

Your method seems too much complex, appart, your problem is you need to read `headers` attribute before reading the other attributes.

Using `com.google.gson.GSon`

```
protected static void read() throws Exception {
    com.google.gson.Gson jParser = new com.google.gson.Gson();

    Reader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(FILE_PATH)));

    // get all the object
    JsonObject json = jParser.fromJson(r, JsonObject.class);

    // get headers object
    JsonObject members = json.get("headers").getAsJsonObject();

    // get attributes inside headers!
    System.out.println(members.get("id"));
    System.out.println(members.get("name"));
    System.out.println(members.get("statusMessage"));
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
"4"
"GLO"
"Hi +234805, an ACCESS FEE of N20.00 will be charged in order to access this Platform"
```

---

[**Download here**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson224jar.htm) the jar files

---

> What varable is `FILE_PATH` – arinze 3 mins ago

Is a path where I placed the file with content you put in your question, in my case:

```
String FILE_PATH = "D:\\Users\\jordi\\datos.txt";
```

but you must put your own path.... anyway, if you need get a `Reader` from an `URL` just use this example:

```
URL url = new URL("http://your-json-url");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

Comment: looks like perfect .

Comment: where is the gson varable. where do i download it

Comment: @arinze no need to GSON . Please check his logic just

Comment: @arinze updated my answer with link to har, but Amiya is right, if you need to use your JSON library just take a look at the logic, if you can change to GSon

Comment: what varable is filepath

Comment: as you can guess... the path to your file!!! `xD` in my case: `private static final String FILE_PATH = "D:\\Users\\jordi\\datos.txt";` but you must put your own path....

Comment: @arinze please kindly check my last update clarifying the source of the json

Comment: did what you suggested this is what i am gettting "07-25 13:33:59.608    6292-6306/? W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.gson.JsonElement com.google.gson.JsonObject.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: also find here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38436453/3850595 an example of reading JSON from an URL

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I do... people don't like to listen how they can improve their code and delete her answer downvoting the suggestor ;).